# Does no conflict of git merge mean everything OK?

Tags: c++, c, git, conflict, merge-conflict-resolution

There are 5 files, a.h, aImpl.c, b.h, bImpl.c, and main.c includes both header files.

```
Branch A:
    //File a.h
    +extern int x;
    //File aImpl.C
    +int x=1
Branch B:
    //File b.h
    +extern int x;
    //File bImpl.C
    +int x=2
```

No file conflicted, but actually global variable conflicted. How git merge will deal in this case?

Comment: git doesn't understand programming languages.  It simply knows that it can apply the changes without ambiguity.

Comment: Is git responsible for debugging code? I thought git just cared about diffs?

Comment: 1001 reasons to compile your code before pushing after merging.

Answer (score 4):

Git's built-in merge works on a textual basis alone.  Syntactic or semantic errors do not concern Git one bit.  In short, the merge will succeed and the code will fail.  It is up to you, not Git, to deal with this.

You can get a little bit of assistance using Git's hooks, e.g., you can disable commits until some test(s) pass.  However, such hooks are left to each user to use or bypass at will.  Writing good hooks is also somewhat difficult, since commits get made from the contents of the index (staging area), not from the contents of the work-tree.